# Is the mystery in Rev. 10:7 referring to the rapture?

Tags: rapture

It appears the mystery mentioned in Rev. 10:7 is referring to the completed mission of the church. (Eph. 3:4-6, 5:32) The combination of Jesus statement in Rev. 10:6 there will be no more delay and the blowing of Trumpet #7 seems to suggest the rapture is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

There are various interpretations about "the rapture" but there is a quick way to dispense with the idea that it is happening in Revelation 10:6-7. Read on:

> "And the voice which I heard from heaven spake unto me again, saying,
> 'Go and take the little book which is open in the hand of the angel
> which standeth upon the sea and upon the earth... And I took the
> little book out of the angel's hand, and ate it up; and it was in my
> mouth sweet as honey: and as soon as I had eaten it, my belly was
> bitter. And he said unto me, 'Thou must prophesy again before many
> peoples, and nations, and tongues, and kings'." Revelation 10:8-11
> A.V.

This shows that there will remain on Earth the prophetic testimony, by personal witness, against the people, nations and kings. There is to be prophecy ***again***, which follows ***after*** the events of verses 6 to 7. Therefore, verses 6 to 7 do not show that there is no longer any Church witness on Earth (all the faithful having been caught up to heaven), nor that any "delay" has ended.

Here now is the long way to dispense with the idea that any rapture is happening in Revelation 10:6-7, and it comes by getting the context of chapter 10, as explained in this book:

> "Now, however, an entirely new scene appears in Chapter 10, ushering
> in an astonishingly different series of visions which continue through
> to the end of the first 13 verses of Chapter 11. These openings seem
> nothing to do with the preceding trumpets of the first six angels. But
> they are everything to do with them. So much so that - continuing on
> from the end of Chapter 9 - they are in fact *part* of the sixth
> trumpet, and of the second woe.
>
> Far from Chapter 10 - and the relevant verses of Chapter 11 - being
> some sort of an interlude, these verses are the very essence, all of
> one with the matter commencing with the words of Revelation 9:12,13,
> 'One woe is past; and behold there come two more woes hereafter. And
> the sixth angel sounded.'
>
> The narrative of the sounding of the sixth angel does not conclude
> until Revelation 11:14,15, 'The second woe' - and therefore the sixth
> trumpet - 'is past: and behold, the third woe cometh quickly. And the
> seventh angel sounded.' Clearly, everything between these two
> quotations records the sounding of the sixth trumpet.
>
> The entire content of Chapter 10 and that of the first 13 verses of
> Chapter 11 *belongs* to the sounding of the sixth trumpet and the
> second woe... The events of Revelation 10:1 to 11:13 *continue* to
> unfold what began with the sounding of the sixth angel. In fact, the
> events of Chapter 9:13-21 are, firstly, connected; secondly,
> concurrent; and thirdly causative." *The Revelation of Jesus Christ*,
> pp. 239-243, John Metcalfe
> http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Try reading in context, from before the two verses you ask about, and include the verses immediately following, and it should become clear that ***this has nothing to do with any rapture, whatever interpretation of that is believed***.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel asked "How long shall it be till the end of these wonders?" (Daniel ch12 v6). He seems to be referring to the description in the immediately previous verses of the "time of trouble" and God's reaction (ch12 v1), immediately followed by the general resurrection (v2). The angel answers Daniel's question in terms of "a time, two times, and half a time" (v7).

The declaration in Revelation ch10 v6 that there will be "time no longer" (or "no more delay") is commonly and rightly (I believe) taken as the termination of the "times" in Daniel.In other words, what is being announced is the coming END of the tribulation, brought about by God's saving response and the general resurrection. These things are described at the end of Revelation, but they are already "imminent" at the blowing of the seventh trumpet. The seventh trumpet announces what might be called the final hour of the present age, and the seven bowls or vials represent the last minutes, as it were, of that hour. (The other chapters are reflections on what is happening rather than fresh events)

This is in accordance with what we find elsewhere in the New Testament,that is the general resurrection and final judgment taking place at the return of Christ. It is what we find in Matthew ch24 vv29-31 and ch25 vv31-45, which outlines the almost simultaneous end of the tribulation, return of Christ, gathering of the elect, and final judgment.

We see the same picture in 1 Thessalonians ch4 vv16-17. When Christ returns, then there is a resurrection of the deceased elect and then "we who are alive will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air; and so we shall always be with the Lord". THAT is the "rapture"; what happens when Christ returns.

So I suggest that this whole drama of "end of tribulation, return of Christ, general resurrection, final judgment" is what is intended by the "mystery" of ch10 v7

Answer (score 0):

Rev 10:6, 7 says (BLB) -

> and he swore by the One living to the ages of the ages, who created
> heaven and the things in it, and the earth and the things in it, and
> the sea and the things in it, "There will be **no more delay**!  But
> in the days of the voice of the **seventh angel**, when he **is about
> to sound the trumpet**, then the mystery of God would be completed, as
> proclaimed to His servants, the prophets."

Note the important clues about this.

1. **Seventh angel** - this refers to the seventh angel's trumpet as recorded in Rev 11:15 -

> And the seventh angel sounded his trumpet, and there were great voices
> in heaven, saying: "The kingdom of the world has become that of our
> Lord and of His Christ, and He will reign to the ages of the ages."

This is recording (in prophetic form) the events that will surround the second coming of Jesus when all peoples will finally be subject to the new kingdom of heaven.

2. **about to sound**

This is the time immediately before the sounding of the seventh trumpet

3. **No more delay/time**

Numerous Bible passages discuss a "delay" between the time of the prophecy and the end of time at Jesus' return.

- Matt 24:6 - "but the end is still to come."
- Matt 24:8 - " these are the **beginning** of birth pains."
- 2 Thess 2:6 - "but the one who now **restrains** it will continue until"

That is, the time of the Rev 10:5-7 is very close to the sounding of the seventh angel's trumpet.

Thus, the events described in Matt 24 and 2 Thess 2 are about to occur without delay in Rev 10 - immediately following those events we will see the coming of the Son of Man in the clouds, the final judgement and the resurrection of the dead - see Matt 24, mark 13 and Luke 21.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Revelation 10:7 7th trumpet and 16:17 7th bowl happen at same time and herald the second coming and the rapture. See Mark 13: 3-27 a one time great tribulation such as has never happened or will happen again, ties trumpets and bowls together. After all of theses tribulations you will see the son of man in the clouds and his angels will gather up the elect/chosen. Then battle at the place called Armageddon, Satan locked up for the 1000 year and Yeshua reigns on this earth. After the 1000 year reign, God's judgement day of all of this creation. You cannot understand Revelation reading it as if written chapter to chapter. Chapters 4-21 are some prophecy and then some history/background, then repeats that sequence three times. You have to separate the prophecy from the history/background. The prophecies are each written in a sequence from start to finish. The history/background each cover different aspects of start to finish and have to be weaved together for the overall picture.